How to remove unwanted options ( nodev, nosuid, nobrowse ) on mount on recent macOS
On macOS Big Sur, how to get rid of unwanted mount options which are automagicaly
added by the diskutil command: nodev, nosuid, nobrowse?
On macOS Big Sur, I noticed that most of the mounted file system are mounted with
nodev, nosuid, nobrowse mount options:
/dev/disk1s4 on /System/Volumes/VM (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /System/Volumes/Preboot (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s6 on /System/Volumes/Update (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s1 on /System/Volumes/Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)

Even when I never set these options.
And I would like to be free to manage the mount options I want.
On trying some experiment, I built 2 APFS volumes, and noticed that mounting them
with diskutil, both are mounted with nodev, nosuid, nobrowse mount options.
But when I mount them with plain old mount -t apfs <volume> <mounting_point>
I get a different results:
/dev/disk7s2 on /Volumes/clone_noether_S (apfs, local, journaled)
/dev/disk7s1 on /Volumes/clone_noether_D (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)

Then a direct mount rather than the macOS diskutil free us of the unwanted nodev, nosuid.
How to further analyse this difference and how to now get rid of this unwanted
nobrowse mount option?
